# Reversibility and its surroundings

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

I was thinking about the definition of reversibility but there is something that I cannot understand. In real life the surrounding of a system (anything else in the universe) is always changing making impossible a reversible process even if the process is slow enough to guaranteed the lack of friction heat loss and this surrounding are not in thermodynamic equilibrium so I cannot understand how people calculated entropy under such conditions, am I wrong in the assumption of choosing the surrounding as everything outside the system or it is enough to choose the immediate surrounding that is in thermodynamic equilibrium?

Answer (score 2):

In thermodynamics, you kind of have to be careful about what is being studied. When we talk about processes being reversible, it is the system, the stuff inside the piston, that we are studying. The surroundings are assumed to be doing the bare minimum, the simplest stuff that allows us to derive the results we want.

In particular, because we are only really interested in the system, we are replacing the actual surroundings with tolerably real but ultimately mathematical fiction. The fiction must be real enough to be an idealisation of a possible system, but otherwise we do not really care what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Although everything not included in the definition of the system is considered the surroundings (i.e., everything in the universe not included in the system), it is generally only the interaction of the system with the *local* *surroundings*, which are in some manner controlled, that is the subject of study, and not the rest of the "universe" where uncontrolled changes may be occurring.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As everything else in thermodynamics, the surroundings is an *idealization*: it is the part of the world outside the system that is affected by what happens to the system. If the system is being heated, the surroundings are the source of that heat, perhaps a bath, or another system that is being cooled. If we are compressing, then the surroundings is the outside pressure that causes the compression; and so on.

To put it a bit more formally, in thermodynamics we study the interaction between *two systems*, one that represents the system of interest (the "system") and one that represents the surroundings. These two systems are assumed to interact with nothing else but themselves. Imagine them in complete isolation of the rest of the world, for example, by enclosing both in a rigid, thermally insulated box.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you want to heat a solid from the initial temperature $T_i$ to the final temperature $T_f$.

You can abruptly apply the temperature $T_f$ to the boundary of the system. in this case, there will be thermal gradients **within** the solid and therefore **creation of entropy within the solid.**

You can also use a heating system by making sure that the temperature at the boundary of the system increases slowly so that there is no thermal gradient inside the solid. But in your heating system, even if the boundary temperature varies slowly there may be temperature gradients, combustions...and so there may be creation of entropy within the heating system. Overall, if you take heating into account, your transformation will not be reversible.

But since entropy is created outside the system, it is traditional to say that the transformation is reversible. This is a way of saying that we could proceed differently and use a "temperature source", which is by definition reversible.

In fact, it is not important! When you calculate an entropy variation on "a reversible path", you use the relation $dS= \frac{\delta Q}{T_{boundary}} + \delta S_i$ assuming that $T_{boundary} = T$ and that $\delta S_i=0$. **What counts is the  absence of entropy creation inside the system.**

You will then have $dS= \frac{\delta Q}{T}$ and you can calculate the entropy variation **of the system** with the usual method. The reversibility of the source play no role in this calculation.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.